# RecyclerView, different ViewTypes and notifyItemMoved() causing visual glitching

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a fairly simple adapter, however the animation seems to be broken;

```
//uses, what is effectly an array, to find out how many views to render
override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

//converts the view position to a layout id
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return data[position].type.editorLayout
}

//renders the view from getItemViewType()
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(viewType, parent, false)
    return TemplateEnum.layoutList[viewType]!!.createEditor(layout)
}

//binds a click event to a view
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        moveDown(position)
    }
}

//updates the data to reflect the event and calls notifyItemMoved() to visually swap the data
private fun moveDown(position: Int) {
    data.moveDown(position)
    notifyItemMoved(position, position + 1)
}
```

When I use this code and I test it (emulator and physical) the views blink and update instantly with no animation.

I have investigated the behaviour, I have found out that the view's `onCreateViewHolder()` that I clicked get's called then its `onBindViewHolder()` then the next view in the recycler's `onBindViewHolder()` is called. I believe this is what is causing the animation glitching, because android is getting confused what to animate.

I have also tested this code using only 1 layout, this results in none of the above events being called, the side effect of this is that the click listeners are never rebound and clicking one view changes the position of other views. I don't know how to fix this.

Seeing as how I cannot get notifyItemMoved() in either instance I am wondering, in part, how I am supposed setup an adapter to work to support it. But primarily I am interested in maintaining the animation on an example using different viewtypes. How could this be achieved?

Comment: I suggest reading how to use ListAdapter. It eliminates the need for calling any of the *notify* functions and is very smart about figuring out proper animations when you make changes to the data. But it does require creating a new data list each time something changes so it can compare old and new to find the changes.